# How can we load a hive table created over json data to spark dataframe using spark.sql?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hive

I tried querying hive table over json data (using spark.sql) into a pyspark dataframe and the following error occured

```
   ERROR log: error in initSerDe: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe not foundjava.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding json serde jar inside `spark.sql`, check below code.

If it is managed table, You can use below code.

```
spark.sql("ADD JAR /path-to/hive-json-serde.jar; SELECT * FROM TABLE")
```

If it is an external table you can directly load data by passing hdfs path.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am fetching data from an external hive table created on some json data to a pyspark dataframe and saving the df as a CSV file.

So in what location i should put the jar file?? In the hive folder or in the local path??
Should i add --jars in spark submit command?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am fetching data from an external hive table created on some json data to a pyspark dataframe and saving the df as a CSV file.

I have used "org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe" while creating my hive table over json. So is this jar file compatible?

1)So in what location i should put the jar file?? In the hive folder or in the local path?? 2)Should i add --jars in spark submit command?

Comment: If it is external table why do you need to add jar, just load that data using hdfs path ??

Comment: put that jar file in some location in hdfs & use that like ADD JAR <hdfs path> inside spark.sql

Comment: How can i load hive data to spark dataframe using location?
We cannot specify location in spark.sql select query right

Comment: not hive data .. if you have data in hdfs & you can load using ```spark.read.format("json").load("hdfs path")```

Comment: My aim is to read the json data in to a pyspark dataframe and make some changes and save as csv on which i need to create another external table. So I cannot read my JSON data to spark dataframe, as the order and number of fields are not same in my hive table create query(i am having around 500 columns in my hive table).So i need to fetch the data from hive table itself